Connecting aws documentdb locally
I can connect to the AWS DocumentDB Cluster using MongoDB Compass successfully on my local machine. It uses SSH connection. It is working.
But, I am struggling to connect to the database from C# code from my local computer.
var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl("mongodb://master:password@abc-mongo.cluster-xyzxyz.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/database?ssl=false&readpreference=secondaryPreferred"));

var client = new MongoClient(settings);
var database = client.GetDatabase("database");
var databases = client.ListDatabases().ToList();

I get the error:
A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : SecondaryPreferred } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/abc-mongo.cluster-xyzxyz.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/abc-mongo.cluster-xyzxyz.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.


What port is used by the mongodb protocol and is it opened all the way between you and AWS? Have you controlled the firewalls etc. in between? Oh its in the code is 27017 open?

Atlas URLs are typically prefixed with mongodb+srv://, not just mongodb://. Not sure if that applies to DocumentDB too.

Maybe the security group is configured to only allow SSH connections which you are not doing in the code.
You could add new rules to you security group to allow you to connect from you local machine IP or you could follow this guide teaching how to connect using ssh from local code. I haven't tested what's in the guide since I don't have documentdb and don't know how yours is configured.
https://paraspatidar.medium.com/connecting-to-mongodb-using-ssh-from-local-code-for-debugging-having-mongo-replica-set-or-direct-ccea64ac27e5
